# "Outer join" like reports

Tags: reporting, relationships

I have a parent and child object.  I want to create a report for these objects.  I can create a report type for the objects.  Now what I want is that for every child object, there is one row in the report, but the report also shows a row for every parent object which has no child objects.  And I want to display the data for all rows in one report, not two reports.  Is this possible, or will SFDC only display rows where there is at least one child object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have read the documentation first, there is an option for allowing this when creating custom report types.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_report_type_objects.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is available, within Report settings itself, you can add a Filter of type "Cross Filter" stating that it should only those display records which have child records. For more details, refer:-
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_cross_filters_create.htm&language=en_US